# SQLExceptionHelper Invalid Input syntax for integer (PL/pgSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to get an integer from a database query:

```sql
SELECT CAST(concat('id_',substr_of_jointable) AS INTEGER) into integervalue 
  FROM books_authors where id_books = booksvalue 
  ORDER BY id_books DESC 
  LIMIT 1;
```

`subsr_of_jointable` is a TEXT with value `authors`. However I always get an error:

> ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "id_authors"
>         Wobei: SQL statement "SELECT CAST(concat('id_',substr_of_jointable)AS INTEGER) FROM books_authors where id_books = books_value ORDER BY id_books DESC LIMIT 1"
>       PL/pgSQL function books_ins_trig_proc() line 125 at SQL statement

Does anyone have an idea why? The column `id_books` `id_authors` is an integer value in the database.

Comment: You are trying to convert a string, `'id_authors'`  to a number - that won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to build a dynamic query inside a PL/pgSQL function, you might want to take a look at this approach.

Data sample

```
CREATE TABLE t (id_authors INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
```

Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(TEXT) RETURNS INT 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS $BODY$
DECLARE i INT;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT id_'|| $1 ||' FROM t LIMIT 1;' INTO i;
  RETURN i;
END;
$BODY$;
```

This example is only to shows how you can concatenate your strings to create a column name inside your dynamic query.

Calling the function

```
SELECT * FROM myfunction('authors');

 myfunction 
------------
          1
(1 Zeile)
```

Further reading:

- [`Execute Dynamic Commands`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)
- [`PL/pgSQL Function Parameters`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-function-parameters/)

Comment: Whats that $1 in your EXECUTE?
Also is this thee execute sql  function? I googled it minutes before :D

Comment: @Dennis `$1` means the first parameter of your function, which in this example contains the value `authors`. If you prefer, you can give it a label in the function signature, e.g. `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(param TEXT)...` and your `EXECUTE` would look like this: `EXECUTE 'SELECT id_'|| param ||' FROM t LIMIT 1;' INTO i;`

Comment: `EXECUTE`, as the name suggests, executes a query based on a string. This makes possible, for instance, to concatenate column and table names, which isn't possible in pure SQL.